# Spinner styles in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, view, spinner

I see spinners (screenshots attached) in Android's settings. Are they available by default or should i code the appropriate adapters?

If they are available by default, from what API level are they available? I'm coing the application for Gingerbread and above. (Example2 doesn't look like a spinner! How is it done? ) Newbie here! pardon my ignorance if this is a basic question.

Thanks.

**Example 1:**

[image][image]

**Exmample 2:**

[image][image]